# Ubuntu 13.04 Running very slow

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, freeze, performance

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 64.  The HD was clean and nothing was on it when I did the install. I have Windows 7 installed on another drive and it runs smooth. The problem I'm having is it is running very slow, freezing on me and taking a few minutes to load. I had 12.04 on the same comp and it ran fine.

> Memory -2.0 GiB
>
> Processor - AMD Athlon 64 Processor 3700+
>
> Disk - 115.9 GB
>
> Graphics - gforce 7900gt 256bit nvidia

Comment: What graphics driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using nvidia binary xorg driver, kernel module and vdpau from nvidia-304(proprietary,tested)

Comment: I also lost my side and top bar.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to activate property drivers (probably for the graphics card)  install Additional Drivers from Ubuntu software center and then activate the recommended driver.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.